# CustomComparator sort objects error

Tags: java, comparator

I keep getting the error

```
The method sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List<InterfaceMessage>, Folder.CustomComparator)
```

on the code...

```
@Override
public void sortByDate(boolean ascending) {
    Collections.sort(messageList, new CustomComparator());
}

class CustomComparator implements Comparator<Message> {
    public int compare(Message message1, Message message2) {
        return message1.getDate().compareTo(message2.getDate());
    }
}
```

I'm trying to compare the dates within each object in a list to order them by their dates. I'm new to making a comparator but I have seen many examples which I've followed but mine doesn't seem to work? I know I haven't done anything with "ascending" yet, I just want to get the basic comparator working.

Any help is appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: your comparator must implement Comparator<InterfaceMessage> not Comparator<Message>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error message the variable `messageList` must be defined as `List<InterfaceMessage>`. however your comparator uses class `Message`, which might be an implementation of `InterfaceMessage`. However there might be other implementations. So the comparator can't reliably deal with the elements of `messageList`.

The solution is, as suggested in comments:

```
class CustomComparator implements Comparator<InterfaceMessage> { /*...*/ }
```

Comment: The listed solution is wrong and doesn't match the comment.

Comment: @Necreaux thanks for mentioning, damn copy pase errors

Comment: @SpaceTrucker - It's copy pas`t`e ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
class CustomComparator implements Comparator<InterfaceMessage>
```